# How to add a new field on a DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am a total beginner on `DynamoDB` and hardly know how to make a working query. But I recently came up with something which is apparently doing what I want.

Here is my question, I now have a table like this:

It has a primary partition key and a primary sort key:

```
Primary partition key
    primaryPartitionIdKey (String)
Primary sort key
    primarySortIdKey (String)
```

But two fields are not enough to do what I need. I would like to add one more.

```
Another field:
    otherFieldIdKey (String)
```

Is that possible, if YES: how should I do it?

I can' see anything on the AWS console for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DynamoDB tables are schemaless, which means that neither the attributes nor their data types need to be defined beforehand. Each item can have its own distinct attributes.

So, your new "field" or attribute will be automatically created upon the first record put/update operation.

See [DynamoDB Core Components](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.TablesItemsAttributes).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to write data to the Music table using the DynamoDB console.

1. Open the DynamoDB console at
   https://console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/.
2. In the navigation pane on the left side of the console, choose
   Tables.
3. In the table list, choose the Music table.
   [image]
4. Select View Items.
   [image]
5. In the Items view, choose Create item.
6. Choose Add new attribute, and then choose Number. Name the field Awards.
   [image]
7. Repeat this process to create an AlbumTitle of type String.
8. Enter the following values for your item:For Artist, enter No One You Know as the value. For SongTitle, enter Call Me Today. For AlbumTitle, enter Somewhat Famous. For Awards, enter 1.
9. Choose Create item.
   [image]
10. Do this one more time to create another item with the same Artist as the previous step, but different values for the other attributes